# add number from Json to SQL table in PowerAutomate desktop

Tags: sql, python-2.x, power-automate-desktop

I'm trying to get data from accounting software per Api by PoweAutomate desktop.
I get Json object and convert it to custom object.
[image]
Then I assign every atribute to a variable for adding it in sql table.
But I have a problem.
This number is read with comma and I have further problem to add it as decimal(18,2) to SQL table `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`
[image]
[image]
I wanted to replace comma to point in Python 2 (available in PoweAutomate desktop), but this variable is taken as tuple, I can't even join this elements. I wanted to parse Json object in Pyhton, but have error `no module` when trying to`import json`.
May be I should change numeric format
[image]
[image]

When I get answer I see dots, than when assigning to variables I see commas.
[image]
I got information from German software, as far as I understand, commas are used.
May be I can somehow modify my SQL query to put the data in?

Comment: json is always text., so have you tried to replace the cpmma with a dot and then try to convert it

Comment: I've taken embedded function for replacement of chars in text, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: no imean your text is 62,72  and double decimal  float must have 62.72  with a dot. sql server is a bit difficult in that regard, every character that doesn't fit causes that error. so please try it with an dot

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution - edit the sql query (next task is date format):

```
INSERT INTO vaouchers(totalGrossAmount(decimal(18,2)) VALUES replace("%totalGrossAmount%",",",".")
```